# need to diminish number by 1 every time message pops up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a little stuck here and don't know how to proceed. need to diminish number by 1 every time message pops up.

```js
var counter = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (counter == 1) {
    counter++;
    $('#cntVal').html(function(i, val) {
      return +val - 2
    });
  } else {
    $('#cntVal').html(function(i, val) {
      return +val - 1
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="cnt">You still have (<span id="cntVal">3</span>) more tries left. Good luck!</p>
```

should have 3 tries only so first message
You still have 2 more tries left.
then
You still have 1 more tries left.

but in this code always show 2 more tries :(

Comment: Please explain more :)

Comment: According to your code always counter value will be one and value will diminish by 2

Comment: yes thats my problem value is always 1 for counter  :(

Comment: @JanAranas how you want to do? it need a listener, such `click` or etc.. you can't diminish just on load like this.

Comment: so what you want always it will be 1 and one more thing there is no use of else part because always if part will be executed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your code, each time `$(document).ready(function(){});` called, for diminish number by one you need to do event trigger.

```js
var counter = 1;
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#cnt').on('click', function() {
    if (counter == 1) {
      counter++;
      $('#cntVal').html(function(i, val) {
        return +val - 1
      });
    } else {
      $('#cntVal').html(function(i, val) {
        return +val - 1
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="cnt">You still have (<span id="cntVal">3</span>) more tries left. Good luck!</p>
```

I have applied event trigger on click at paragraph.

Comment: you can't do like that. this is what when you will be click on para it will be diminished

Comment: Problem is not exact

Comment: I just add snippet to your `answer` and fix one issue. `return +val - 2` => `return +val - 1`

Comment: all good now thanks for the answer :) .. i modified a little :) thanks for the help